# Adding additional constraints to a generic type in function to a class level generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Consider the following code

```
   public class DrivedDbContext  : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<M> GetDbSet<M>() where M : class
       {
           //Returns the DbSet of the Entity type M
       }
   )
    public interface IActivatable
    {
        Boolean IsActive
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    public class RepositryBase<M> : IRepository<M> where M : class
    {
        private DrivedDbContext dbContext = new DrivedDbContext();

        public List<M> ReadAll<M>()
        {
            dbContext.GetDbSet<M>().ToList();
        }


        public List<ActiveM> ReadActiveAll<ActiveM>() where ActiveM : M, IActivatable
        {
            dbContext.GetDbSet<ActiveM>().Where(X => X.IsActive).ToList();         // <--- Compiler Error
        }
    )
```

The following line shows a compiler error,

```
dbContext.GetDbSet<ActiveM>().Where(X => X.IsActive).ToList();
```

> CS0452 : The type ActivM must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter M in the generic type of method DrivedDbContext.GetDbSet()

I just wanted to ensure that the type M implemented with IActivatable interface only able to call the ReadActiveAll function. What is the correct way to achieve this requirment?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to use `where Active : class`

Comment: Please show us code that we can run to see your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to pass M as generic type in the method ReadAll if it's the same type that the generic type M of the class

```
public List<M> ReadAll()
```

Second, you need to specify that the generic type ActiveM is a class because is a constraint for the method GetDbTest

```
public List<ActiveM> ReadActiveAll<ActiveM>() where ActiveM : M, class, IActivatable
```